# How to calculate difference in month in dbplyr (R and sql)

Tags: sql, r, date, impala, dbplyr

I tried to calculate the difference between dates in months for a huge database, using dbplyr package which sends my codes to the sql query. I tried different ways suggested in similar questions, but they didn't work (for example the codes below). Data2 is an object created by `tbl()`

```
Data2 %>% mutate(age_Months = (lubridate::interval(date_1, date_2)) / base::months(1))

#OR

library(lubridate)
Data2 %>% mutate(age_Months = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, date_1, date_2))
```

Do you have any ideas to calculate the differences? Feel free to suggest any other libraries and functions, it's not matter. I just need the differences in month. Thank you

The data set is as below.

```
Data2 %>% select(date_1, date_2) %>% head() %>% collect()

#  date_1                date_2               
#  <chr>                 <chr>                
#1 2015-05-01 00:00:00.0 2036-02-01 00:00:00.0
#2 2015-05-01 00:00:00.0 2036-01-01 00:00:00.0
#3 2015-05-01 00:00:00.0 2031-03-01 00:00:00.0
#4 2015-05-01 00:00:00.0 2035-12-01 00:00:00.0
#5 2015-05-01 00:00:00.0 2035-05-01 00:00:00.0
#6 2015-05-01 00:00:00.0 2032-03-01 00:00:00.0
```

I transformed them by `as.Date()` but no difference happened in result.

```
Data2 %>% mutate(date_1 = as.Date(date_1),
                 date_2 = as.Date(date_2))
#  date_1     date_2    
#  <date>     <date>    
#1 2018-08-01 2036-02-01
#2 2018-08-01 2036-06-01
#3 2018-08-01 2036-01-01
#4 2018-08-01 2034-08-01
#5 2018-08-01 2033-08-01
#6 2018-08-01 2035-03-01
```

Comment: `(date_2 - date_1) / 30`, optionally with `round(.)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possible approaches.

###### 1) Using lubridate

dbplyr translations are defined for some (but not all) lubridate functions into some (but not all) SQL flavors (when last I tested). So I would start by trying the following:

```r
Data2 %>%
  mutate(year1 = lubridate::year(date_1),
         year2 = lubridate::year(date_2),
         month1 = lubridate::month(date_1),
         month2 = lubridate::month(date_2)) %>%
  mutate(age_months = 12*(year2 - year1) + month2 - month1) %>%
  select(-year1, -year2, -month1, -month2)
```

###### 2) Using untranslated SQL functions

Impala includes a `DATEDIFF` function (documentation [here](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html#datetime_functions__datediff)). When dbplyr encounters a comand that it does not have a translation defined for, it passes the command untranslated through to the database.

So something like the following:

```r
Data2 %>%
  mutate(age_months = DATEDIFF(date_2, date_1) / 30)
```

should be translated into SQL like this:

```sql
SELECT *
    ,DATEDIFF(date_2, date_1) / 30 AS age_months
FROM data2
```